# What are the effects on loading times when conditionally loading and concatenating scripts?

Tags: javascript, performance

Suppose you have a script in your theme that you always need on every page - say 'animate-menu.js' (10KB) - and you have one that you only need on one specific page - say 'validate-contactform.js' (5KB). Both are enqueued separately.

There are two best practices regarding optimization of scripts loading times:

- **Conditional loading**: We could enqueue 'animate-menu.js' only when we need it using a if statement to test for `has_shortcode($post->post_content, 'contact-form')` or `is_page('Contact')`. This would reduce the initial loading times as only the needed scripts get loaded.
- **Script concatenation (aka minification)**: Using a plugin we could combine all the scripts into one. This will result in a bigger script file but reduce the number of HTTP requests and result in faster loading times on all future page loads.

Using either of these methods will (theoretically) result in the same loading times overall:

**Conditional loading**
I'm on the homepage: load 'animate-menu.js' (10KB)
Next, I'm on the contact page: use 'animate-menu.js' from browser cache and load 'validate-contactform.js' (5KB)
*Loaded in total:* 15KB

**Script concatenation**
I'm on the homepage: load 'animate-menu.js,validate-contactform.js' (15KB)
Next, I'm on the contact page: *use both scripts from browser cache*
*Loaded in total:* 15KB

Deciding which method you choose depends on the special situation of your site. In some cases you want your homepage to load fast and avoid all unnecessary requests. If only 1% of your users will hit the contact page there is no need to make the other 99% force to download the validation script. In other cases it can be ok to let the users wait a little longer initially and then have the next pages load faster.

**There is however a problem when combining both of these two methods:**

I'm on the homepage: load 'animate-menu.js' (10KB)
Next, I'm on the contact page: load 'animate-menu.js,validate-contactform.js' (15KB)
Loaded in total: 25KB

The conditional loading and concatenation will result in different versions of the big file and the browser can not tell it already loaded parts of it previously.

This is a question that arose during a Q&A session at this years WordCamp Europe. We agreed that conditional loading is the *better* practice but it should be measured in each case.

Does anybody have the time to do this in the past and/or can speak from experience in other cases? Is combining conditional loading and script concatenation generally a bad idea?

(Disclaimer: I ignore the fact that many people will not see homepage first but will have a sub-page as their entry-page; it doesn't make a lot of difference for the discussion here.)

Comment: How is this a wordpress specific question?

Comment: Just as a note: By no means is concatenation the same as what is commonly understood as minimization. Or in other words, combining files to reduce requests and minifying them reduce file size are just two different things - both of them could and probably should be done though.

Comment: On the topic, personally I'm thinking about, but haven't tackled it yet to make this WordPress inherent, making use of file concatenation via Apache and `.htaccess`. As an example, kind of how you can find it inside the [htaccess file of the html5 boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess#L777).

Comment: @MarkKaplun Plugins become more and more powerful and people aren't WP just for their blogs anymore. Say you install Woocommerce, The Events Calendar, a front end media uploader and use the Toolbar you can easily end up with 30+ script tags in your theme. I'd like to know how other people think about this and how we deal with it as developers.

Comment: @JanBeck, if you can ask exactly the same question about drupal, amd you cam, the question is not wordpress specific and therefor off-topic for this site.

Comment: @MarkKaplun what would be a better place to ask this question?

Comment: @JanBeck, I am actually not sure. Maybe best to try to ask keizer or rarst on chat as they are probably much more familiar with the various stacks then me.

Comment: I have to disagree, just because the general topic isn't WordPress specific it - IMHO - does not mean the question is off topic. @MarkKaplun Besides, Jan beck does explicitly state that this question has its origin at a Q&A session at WCEU, so clearly this is obviously of interest for WordPress developers. Additionally, the question is about, how to handle this in a WordPress context, which will differ from general or other approaches.

Comment: Last but not least, [wordpress.se] still is about plug-ins, themes and includes optimizing of administered installations too. Otherwise [wordpress.se] really just degenerates to a how to use this WordPress function stack, without any development claim whatsoever and that can't be the goal. Personally I think, if anything one could say, this falls under the »too broad« or »unclear what you're asking« category. Anyhow, just my 2 cents on this.

Comment: Note: the last comment might in parts be a bit over-dramatic

Comment: @ialocin, the telling sign it is not wordpress specific is that neither wordpress, themes or plugins or any API is mentioned in it. The only wordpress specific info given in it was that it was asked in a WC in which questions like "what is the best way to the train station" were asked as well ;).  IMO this is a question with no definitive answer as it depends on the type of traffic the site has and maybe some server side related attributes but it is a fine question, just the wrong forum.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I'm not going to nit pick ;) Is it WordPress specific enough, probably not, but as I said in such cases »too broad« or »unclear what you're asking« are a way better fit then »off topic«. Aside from that, I'm perfectly fine with letting the community decide, I just don't always agree.

Comment: As a moderator I think this doesn't pass "does question change if you remove WordPress from it" test for specificity, but I do not feel about it strongly enough to butt in with my binding close vote. :) Leaving it up to community. I think SO would fit for it, I have asked web performance questions there before.

Comment: @MarkKaplun my name is _Kaiser_, not _Keizer_ :)

Comment: Thanks Solomon, eh @Rarst, just lets see who is willing to rip the child apart.

Comment: Right now there is a related discussion happening kicked off by Chris Coyer on this Gist more generally towards how plugins enqueue script and style dependencies: https://gist.github.com/chriscoyier/2074e17ce9ae5e6d537e

Answer (score 1):

I have found that you get the best performance by using a combination.   I tend to use:

- A core combined JavaScript file that contains a concatenation of all the JavaScript that is required for every page on the site.   In my case this includes jQuery as well as code for lightboxes and menus.

  - Served as a separate file so that it is cached between page views: `<script src="combined-v1234.js"></script>`
  - Versioned by the build system (the `1234`) so that users get a new version of it whenever I release newe code to the website.  If a browser gets an *older* version that what is available they get a 301 permanent redirect to the current version.  If a browser requests a *newer* version than what is available they get a 302 temporary redirect to prevent pre-caching.
- Code specific to a particular page is included inline conditionally: `<script>var contactpage=true;</script>`

In both cases I use [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) to minimize the files as part of the build process so that the web server is serving smaller files.

Comment: I agree with concatenation in general, but *especially* if the files are only 15KB as in the question. Additionally, it's better if the combined file is served directly as a static file and not concatenated on-the-fly via Wordpress.